# How to change the text color using tkinter.Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to build my first GUI program and want to know who to change the label text color? for instance, changing it to 'red'

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="what's my favorite video?", pady=10, padx=10, font=10,)
label.pack()
click_here = tk.Button(root, text="click here to find out", padx = 10, pady = 5)
click_here.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Add `fg='red'` in `tk.Label(...)`.

Comment: try 

bg='#fff' or fg='f00' in tk.label

Answer (score 17):

You can use the optional arguments `bg` and `fg` (Note that you might need to use a different option like `highlightbackground` on MacOS system as stated [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591118/10145519) ) - which I believe is a known issue with `tk.Button` on MacOS.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# bg is to change background, fg is to change foreground (technically the text color)
label = tk.Label(root, text="what's my favorite video?",
                 bg='#fff', fg='#f00', pady=10, padx=10, font=10) # You can use use color names instead of color codes.
label.pack()
click_here = tk.Button(root, text="click here to find out",
                       bg='#000', fg='#ff0', padx = 10, pady = 5)
click_here.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The only reason I added this as an answer is because the [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208140/10145519) I wrote on a similar question for someone on SO, didn't work just because they were using a Mac. If you are on a Windows machine, you are fine.

Comment: @JackGriffin i'm not sure what that means. `#f00` will always represent red regardless of its host OS.

Comment: @P S Solanki : you're right.I misunderstood your code.My fault.Will delete that comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bg='#fff'` or `fg='f00'` in `tk.label`.

Answer (score 0):

note that `background=''` returns a label to its default color. I found this by printing the result of `label.cget('background')` where label is a tkinter label.

Comment: Does not work on Linux (Kubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="what's my favorite video?", pady=10, padx=10, font=10, fg="red")
label.pack()

click_here = tk.Button(root, text="click here to find out", padx=10, pady=5)
click_here.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="what's my favorite video?", pady=10, padx=10, font=10, text_color="red")
```

use the argument 'text_color' to chnage your label text's colour